# Filter ListView by tags and not by content

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
data_set = [
    {"Google", "Search, Android, Adwords"},
    {"Apple", "iPhone, iCloud, iPod, Mac, OSX"},
    {"Microsoft", "Windows, PC, Adwords"},
    {"Nokia", "Lumia, 3310"},
    {"Amazon", "Shopping"}
]
```

I can create a ListView that displays "Google", "Apple", "Microsoft", "Nokia", and "Amazon", with filtering enabled. However, when a user presses a key, I want it to filter the data based on the tags, eg. "Search, Android, Adwords" for Google, and not based on the name of the company.